# Python for-loop won't iterate past first character in stirng

Tags: python, string, for-loop

My python function is supposed to take an input that is a string (of only letters and only lowercase letters). The function should output true if there are no repeating letters ( regardless of whether they are consecutive letters or not) and it's suppose to return false if there are repeating letters. My code only checks if the first letter is repeating or not, but doesn't check any other letter in the string. What is the issue?

[image: my code]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def is_isogram(string):
    for x in string:
        if string.count(x) > 1:
            return False
    return True
```

You want to return `True` only if you pass through all the `for loop`

Comment: It worked with your code ! Thank you very much.  So the else statement in my initial code made it go through one iteration?

Comment: Excectly, in the first iteration, by default it would always return `True` and then it would exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

the following should rectify.

```py
def is_isogram(s: str):

    # loop through all unique chars
    for x in set(s):
        if s.count(x) > 1:
            return True

    # terminate after looping through all chars
    return False
```

additionally convert string to a set to eliminate iterating over same char twice.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making it past the first character because in the first iteration of the for loop, your "else" exits the function if the if statement returns false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the thing is when I entered "deff" it still returned True although the first letter is not repeating. So I think it still just runs one iteration regardless of whether the first iteration is false or true.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
def is_isogram(x): 
    if len(str(x)) > len(set(x)): 
        return False 
    else: 
        return True
```